# Changing WP7 app from free to paid

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am thinking of chaqnging one my app from free to paid to further support the development. If do this change and enabled a trial, what wil hapen with existing users after they update the app from marketplace? Will they have the full paid version or will they be in trial? It does not seem fair if they wil get stuck in trial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone who installs your app while it is free has basically purchased your app for free. So if you update the price, it won't affect those users because they've already "purchased" the app. They'll receive any further updates to the full version of your app.

Comment: Just to clarify (hopefully), if they had the free version before you made it paid and they upgrade they will have the full rather than the trial version of the app.